# The RedirectUri passed in the authentication properties is not being applied when calling the challenge

Tags: c#, owin, openid-connect

I am using OpenId Connect protocol to authenticate in my application. In the Startup.cs file I have all challenges configured (login, register, change password, etc) with the returnUrl like 'https://domain.com/en-IE/Home/Index' but when I am calling the challenge I want to change the returnUrl using the current culture the user is in... For that I am calling the following:

```
public static void SignIn(this IOwinContext context)
{      
      var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = 'https://domain.com/ga-IE/Home/Index' };
      context.Authentication.Challenge(authProperties, ClientSettings.Login);
}
```

So, my problem is that I can see the returnUrl as en-IE and not the new passed ga-IE.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is not clear whether you are referring to the IdP to app traffic, or to the intra-app traffic. I will assume the former.
The RedirectUri property of AuthenticationProperties is not the same RedirectUri you specify in the middleware options. Here there's a quote from my upcoming [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735696942) that might help to clarify:

> It is an unfortunate coincidence that the RedirectUri property just
>   described happens to be named exactly the same as an OAuth2/OpenID
>   Connect protocol parameter. The value passed in Challenge is not sent
>   to Azure AD and used as part of the protocol dance: it is a local
>   value that is used after the authentication dance takes place. All
>   redirect URIs used by Azure AD must be explicitly registered for
>   security reasons, and it is clearly not feasible to register all
>   possible controller actions as return URIs. That’s why Azure AD
>   normally associates only a few return URIs with each app (typically
>   one for every deployment root) and the middleware itself takes care of
>   performing local redirects without involving the IdP to ensure that
>   requests land on the correct resource.